# Python UI gets unresponsive after long run

Tags: python, pyqt, multiprocessing, pyside

I do have a strange problem. I have a two-process apllication written in python and PySide for the GUI.

The GUI runs in the first thread and spwans a second process (to prevent the python GIL) in which a measurement-statemachine is running. Once started this FSM sends messages over a socket to the host-application (for communication). This FSM execution time is often very long (5 hours).

The problem now is that somehow the host-application gets unresponsive. The UI doesn't update anymore (Received messages from second process are not shown anymore) and Windows saying the application is not reponsive. The second process still works correctly.

Can anyone help me how to debug this? This only happens for very long running FSMs and when there is much to do in the FSM. Could this be a general ressource problem?

Edit:
The code below firs t shows the run-method of the thread capturing the messages from the second processes. This calls the callback which is defined below. This callback only emits signals (and feed them with the received data) to update the UI (for e.g. log to UI).

```
class RunnerServer(QThread):
    # ...
    def run(self):
        try:
            self._socket.bind((self._host, 0))
            self._port = self._socket.getsockname()[1]
            self._is_started.set()
            while not self._stop_event.is_set():
                try:
                    data = self._socket.recvfrom(2048)[0]
                except socket.error :
                    continue
                if self._callback:
                    o = pickle.loads(data)
                    self._callback(o, *self._args, **self._kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
        finally:
            self._socket.close()


class Controller:
    # ...
    def remote_server_rx_callback(self, message, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(message, RunnerMessage):
            self._sig_log_msg.emit(lmessage.message_type, message.message, message.source
        elif isinstance(message, StatusMessage):
            if message.message_type == StatusType.START:
                self._sig_runner_started.emit()
            elif message.message_type == StatusType.FINISH:
                self._sig_runner_finished.emit()
            elif message.message_type == StatusType.PROGRESS:
                self._sig_runner_update_progress.emit(message.payload['progress'])
```

Comment: Could you post some example code to help you to spot the problem? Multi-threading with GUI is tricky sometimes.

Comment: @xndrme I've added some code pieces.

Comment: not seeing anything wrong with the thread vs signals. Does this happen after there are lots of log messages? If you remove code that spawns process and replace the socket stuff with code that just emits the same text message over and over do you see the same slow-down? After how many messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bottleneck. It's neiter the socket communication nor emitting the signals. The connected slots prints this to a textfield using `QTextEdit.insertHtml(msg)`. This method call is reposnsible for the unresponsness.

I will now try to remove that view and add instead a TableView. The messages then are appended to the attached model. I hope this will perform better - Or are there better approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I solve this kind of problems by calling `QtGui.qApp.processEvents()` inside a running loop.

For example if I have a `for` loop processing lot of information (which sometimes makes the window unresponsive), I call `QtGui.qApp.processEvents()` at the end of the loop. This call makes the GUI responsive by processing all the events. In other words, this will update the window.

Coming to your problem, I don't know exactly at which point in your code the window gets unresponsive, I think `processEvents()` can be usefull for you.

Comment: The main UI is pretty async. There is actually no such **long running method** in UI thread. In the host process there is a second thread handing the received messages and then emitting signals to update UI. The UI doesn't get suddenly unresponsive. It's more when the FSM is running longer. It seems that for some reason the main process doesn't get any resources anymore. Since the UI thread is async I think there is no real place to put `processEvents()`. Calling this from the socket thread is I think not possible/useful?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is true that second process works correctly, I'm wondering if your host is directly taking messages from an auxiliary thread (that reads from socket) and putting directly in GUI. You can only manipulate the GUI from the main thread, so that could be one problem.

Comment: You are right. There is one SocketReceiveThread in the host process. This emits QT-signals for doing some UI-magic. (e.g. write received log message to UI)

Comment: So SocketReceiveThread only uses signals, doesn't directly call any UI method whatsoever? Care to show this part of your code in your question?